# whea_uncorrectable_error windows 10

Tags: windows, bsod

I have bought a new pc.
i get a bsod every few minutes with whea_uncorrectable_error.
i don't know what to do.
i have uploaded the dmp file, can someone help me find out the cause of the problem.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxnSRoIrmJPdUjRfOWpvUGNWZUU/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxnSRoIrmJPdZGlCdnIzS2ZvV0U/view?usp=sharing

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The [Translation LookAside Buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer) of the L1 Cache of your CPU has issues, which results in the [0x124 Bugcheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557321(v=vs.85).aspx)

**Bug Check 0x124: WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR**

> The WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR bug check has a value of 0x00000124. This
>   bug check indicates that a fatal hardware error has occurred. This bug check uses the error data that is provided by the Windows Hardware Error Architecture (WHEA).

Dumping the error record shows this TLB error `GTLBL1_ERR`:

```
1: kd> !errrec ffffe000535fa028
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ ffffe000535fa028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d15a9b65ed9149
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 1/29/2016 13:47:25 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe000535fa0a8
Section       @ ffffe000535fa180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : TLB error
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 1
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000306d4
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000001

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe000535fa0f0
Section       @ ffffe000535fa240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000001
CPU Id        : d4 06 03 00 00 08 10 01 - bf fb fa 7f ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ ffffe000535fa240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe000535fa138
Section       @ ffffe000535fa2c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : GTLBL1_ERR (Proc 1 Bank 2)
  Status      : 0xb200000000000019
```

This is an issue with the i5-5250U CPU or the motherboard. Try a UEFI/BIOS update and this doesn't fix it, bring the device back to where you bought it and get a new device.